# Plotly R hidding all labels, ticks, legend,etc

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

I am trying to remove all text around a bar plot using Plotly R plot (bar chart, but it is not working as you can see.

Image [now](https://brainet-b.user.sharcnet.ca/index.php/s/JtW5zD8ybkRZSP7)

Image [goal](https://brainet-b.user.sharcnet.ca/index.php/s/LEGj8TAHf6TA5Lc)

This is the code I used to create image "now".

```
library(plotly)

left=30
right=70

data = data.frame(left,right)

ax <- list(title = "", zeroline = FALSE, showline = FALSE,showticklabels = FALSE,showgrid = FALSE, showlegend = FALSE, showgrid=FALSE)
scene = list(xaxis = ax, yaxis = ax)

plot_ly(type = 'bar', orientation = 'h') %>%
  add_trace(x = left,
            marker = list(color = 'rgba(246, 78, 139, 0.6)',
                          line = list(color = 'rgba(246, 78, 139, 1.0)',width = 1)),
            hoverinfo = 'text', text = paste0("Left=",data$left,"%") , hoverinfo="all",
            hoverlabel = list(bgcolor="#272b30",bordercolorsrc ="#272b30",bordercolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",font=list(color="white", size=12, family="sans-serif"))) %>%
  add_trace(x = right,
            marker = list(color = 'rgba(58, 71, 80, 0.6)',
                          line = list(color = 'rgba(58, 71, 80, 1.0)',width = 1)),
            hoverinfo = 'text', text = paste0("Right=",data$right,"%") , hoverinfo="all",
            hoverlabel = list(bgcolor="#272b30",bordercolorsrc ="#272b30",bordercolor="rgba(0,0,0,0)",font=list(color="white", size=12, family="sans-serif"))) %>% 
  layout(paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)', plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
         scene = scene,showlegend = FALSE,barmode = 'relative', autosize = F, margin = list(l=0,r=0,t=0,b=0,pad=0))
```

Thanks

Comment: Add `xaxis = list(tickvals=NULL), yaxis = list(tickvals=NULL)` options inside `layout`.

Comment: Are you sure ? This is what I get: https://imgur.com/a/SPg9Qp8 It seems exactly what you want.